# Build date range aggregation with the new version of elastic search (8.5.3)

Tags: elasticsearch

[private method to build date range aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhDZj.png)
am trying to replace all the deprecated code when migrating from elasticsearch version 7.17 to 8.5.3
am facing an issue that am not able to find the alternatives of the deprecated ones.
is there anyone have working with aggregations, buckets or subaggregations in the new versions of elastic ?

I noticed that everything now is working with lambda but still don't figure out all the alternative features presented by elasticsearch new java client for 8.5.3 version

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply an import/classpath problem in your IDE?

Comment: yes am sure the whole logic has changed

Comment: Hi there, please update your post with the plain text format of your code rather than image file~